# Show first 5 child elements and hide them when next button is clicked and display next 5 with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So what I'm trying to do is, depending on how many paragraphs the user has, the page only displays the first 5. If you click next, it would hide the first 5 paragraphs and display the next 5... So on and so forth.

So far I seem like I've gotten to work somewhat correct. Only problem is, when I reach the end of the paragraphs I am no longer to click "previous" button to go back.

```
<div id="container">

<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
<p>6</p>
<p>7</p>
<p>8</p>
<p>9</p>
<p>10</p>
<p>11</p>
<p>12</p>
<p>13</p>
<p>14</p>
<p>15</p>
<p>10</p>
<p>11</p>
<p>12</p>
<p>13</p>
<p>20</p>


<button class="prev" disabled="disabled">Prev</button>
<button class="next">Next </button>

$('#container p:gt(4)').hide();

$('.prev').click(function() {
    var first = $('#container').children('p:visible:first');
    first.prevAll(':lt(5)').show();

    if(first.prevAll().length < 6){
          $('.prev').attr('disabled', false); 
    }

    first.prev().nextAll().hide();
    $('.next').show();

});

$('.next').click(function() {
    var last = $('#container').children('p:visible:last');
    last.nextAll(':lt(5)').show();

    if(last.nextAll().length < 6){ 
         $('.next').attr('disabled', false);
    }

    $('.prev').show(); 
    last.next().prevAll().hide(); 


});
```

View my jfiddle here, and check what I'm doing wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/h8G7t/

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an updated fiddle with this corrected. http://jsfiddle.net/h8G7t/1/

You had a few issues going on. First is that you were enabling/disabling your buttons incorrectly (setting them to false, when they should have been true). And you weren't toggling the enabled state of the opposite button when needed.

The main issue was that your `nextall` and `prevall` needed to have a selector for the `p` tags because they were picking up the button elements and breaking the navigation.

```
if(last.nextAll('p').length < 6){ ... }
```

Comment: Enabling the opposing button shouldn't be part of the if statement that determines if the end has been reached, it should be outside of it.  If you've pressed next any number of times, you should be able to press prev and vice versa: http://jsfiddle.net/h8G7t/2/.